# JSON file getting passed as JavaScript object in Express Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using the following line to import a JSON file in my code. However, instead of a config file, the `jsonConfig` variable is getting a JavaScript object and I can directly access, `jsonConfig.children`. Why is this happening? And how can I just import a JSON file instead of the object?

```
const jsonConfig = require('../../config/myconfig.json');
```

Comment: That's what's _supposed_ to happen. If you want the file content as text (which is what I assume you mean by "import a json file", but it's not entirely clear what you want or why), use `fs` to read it.

Comment: Here's [a reference to the documentation](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/modules.html#file-modules) for `require()`: "and `.json` files are **parsed** as JSON text files."

Answer (score 0):

That's what's supposed to happen using your method, if you want to access the contents of the file as a text you should use fs

```
fs.readFile('../../config/myconfig.json', function read(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    const content = data;

    // Invoke the next step here however you like
    console.log(content);   //Here you have the contents of your file

});
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON is stand for Javascript Object Notation, so a JSON is a valid object in javascript for that reason you are getting an object, you can access to the values using object notation, if want to get a string you can use JSON.stringify to convert your object into a string.

```
const jsonConfig = require('../../config/myconfig.json');
const jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonConfig);
```